# Liveliness Probe and Readiness Probe for spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring batch application which is to be deployed in kubernetes. it doesn't include spring-boot-starter-web since it's just running cron jobs. is there any way to expose spring-actuator health end points without adding the starter-web dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch applications are ephemeral by nature. It does not make sense to expose an actuator endpoint for the duration of the job (would the job still be running when you query the endopoint?). This has been discussed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21024.

> Liveliness Probe and Readiness Probe for spring batch

Same here. A readiness probe is typically used to see if a service is ready to accept requests. I'm not sure if it makes sense to have a readiness probe for batch jobs. A liveliness probe however could make sense (to see if a job is "live", in which case one needs to define what "live" means), but I've never seen an implementation for such a probe in practice as there are other means to report if a job is running or not (such as live metrics with micrometer for instance).